# Don't Understand Output from MySQL LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a Bash ETL process that takes a CSV file, fixes its format (if required) and loads the content into a MariaDB database. I've found that the records saved to the database are fewer than those in the file and I'm trying to understand why. As part of that process, I added `-vv` to the `mysql` command to see what it's doing and the output is throwing me.

The file I'm importing has **366** lines (including the header).

My command:

```
out=$(mysql -h ${host} \
      -vv \
      -P ${port} \
      -u ${user} \
      -p"${password}" \
      --local-infile \
      my_table < ${scriptDir}/${target}.sql 2>&1)
```

The relevant response looks like this (I added line breaks):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/mydata.csv' 
  REPLACE INTO TABLE my_table CHARACTER SET utf8 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
         OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
  IGNORE 1 LINES 
  SET updated_at = NOW() 
-------------- 
Query OK, 410 rows affected, 1460 warnings 
Records: 365 Deleted: 45 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 1460 Bye
```

This is the first import into the table. Any idea what could be causing 45 records to be deleted by this statement?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As requested, here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `First Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Last Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Campaign Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Event Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Live Views Duration` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `On Demand Views Duration` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job Title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reg Date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Affiliate Data` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone 1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Postal Code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Industry` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uix_conversion` (`Email`,`Campaign Name`,`Event Date`),
  KEY `ix_campaign_name` (`Campaign Name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=512 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**UPDATE**

After some time away, I've removed the unique index with no change. I also changed the `REPLACE` query to an `IGNORE` query and records are now skipped rather than deleted. Same net impact. Moreover, in testing the same file several times, it seems that the missing records are not always the *same* missing records. No idea what's happening here...

Comment: You're using `REPLACE INTO`. Are you certain there aren't duplicate records in the import file? Though I've never tested it, I would expect them to be loaded then later replaced.

Comment: My version 5.7.16 uses `Duplicates:` there, rather than `Deleted:` so I am not sure if this is comparable.

Comment: Please provide the `create` of the table?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I don't believe so. It appears that records simply aren't making it from the CSV file to the database.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've updated the question with the table definition. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I didn't even notice the 1460 warnings. Does `SHOW WARNINGS` tell you anything if executed immediately after the import?

Comment: A common source for warning on `LOAD DATA INFILE` is the imported string values being larger than the size of their destination column. Also an unexpected format of the date values in the `DATE` columns (`Event Date`, `updated_at`).

Comment: Well, make the varchars wider and put the bad dates in @variables so you can fix them.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) explains it pretty clear:

> The `REPLACE` and `IGNORE` keywords control handling of input rows that duplicate existing rows on unique key values:
>
> - If you specify `REPLACE`, input rows replace existing rows. In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index as an existing row.

If your table is empty when you run the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command it means that some of the rows you imported from the `.csv` file contain duplicate values in a column that is imported into the `PK` of the table or into a column that has an `UNIQUE INDEX` on it.

If a row that is about to be imported contain values that duplicate the values of an already imported row in the `PK` or `UNIQUE INDEX` column, the `REPLACE` keyword makes the already imported row to be deleted in order to make room for the new row (to not violate the `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` constraint).

**Updated the answer after you posted the table definition:** search for duplicates in the `id` column and also for rows that have the same set of values in the `Email`,`Campaign Name`,`Event Date` columns of the input `.csv` file.

**Update #2** (after the OP's comment):
If the `.csv` file contains not-empty values in the column `id`, those values imported and the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property of the `id` column doesn't count.

You can skip the `id` column from being imported (and let the `AUTO_INCREMENT` do its job) by specifying the list of columns to be set with data from the `.csv` file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/mydata.csv' 
  REPLACE INTO TABLE my_table CHARACTER SET utf8 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
         OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
  IGNORE 1 LINES 
  (`First Name`, `Last Name`,   # put the rest of the column names here
                                # in the same order they are in the .csv file
                                # put a variable (like @a) to skip a column
                                # or to use the value in an expression in the SET clause
   `Country`, `Industry`)       # but do not put `id`
  SET updated_at = NOW()
```

The columns that do not appear in the list and are not set in the `SET` clause will be set with their `DEFAULT` values (this is where `AUTO_INCREMENT` is invoked for `id`).

Comment: Thanks, but here's the source of my confusion: the `id` field is an auto increment. should never be duplicated, right? And, keying on email, the database is missing several email addresses that exist in the file. In a `REPLACE` scenario, it should exist at least once...right?

Comment: The value of `id` is automatically generated if and only if you don't provide a value for it (or provide `NULL`) in the query. The `LOAD DATA INFILE` query provides a way to specify what fields to load from file: put the list of columns in parentheses just before the `SET` clause. All the fields that are not present in the list and are not set in the `SET` clause will be set with their default value (which is the auto-incremented value for `id`).

Comment: Right. I should have specified, that there is no id in the file and nothing is being set. It's a unique identifier for convenience only (we have a couple of self-joining queries). In fact, I drop and re-add it right before running the import because it's _only_ used at runtime for self joins.

Comment: In this case probably there are duplicates on the combination of `Email`, `Campaign Name`, `Event Date` columns. Check the combinations in the `.csv` file against those already existing in the database.